# CSS fixed position while centering horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have the following css on an element in my html.  It centers the image horizontally but its not at the bottom of the page where i need it to be.  How do i change this css to keep it centered horizontally but make it position: fixed to the bottom?

```
background: url(loginv1.png)50% 50% no-repeat;
background-size: 75px 25px;
height: 40px;
width: 120px;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: You want the box horizontally centered + fixed at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Le7yP/15/

```
div {
  background: url(http://snag.gy/z01qo.jpg) 50% 50%/75px 25px no-repeat;
  height:40px;
  width:120px;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-60px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The background positioning format is:

```
background: url("...") horizontal vertical;
```

Therefore, specify your background as follows:

```
background: url("loginv1.png") center bottom no-repeat;
background-size: 75px 25px;
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cJ75z/) example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
background: url("loginv1.png") center bottom no-repeat;
```

This will place the background image at the *center* horizontally, and at the *bottom* vertically.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9FbZ/1/)**